# Where can I find the test_ros package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I tried to run the test cases of rosmsg but they depend on a 'test_ros' package that is not listed in the package xml and also not listed in the repositories. Can someone tell me where I can get this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220696/where-can-i-find-the-test_ros-package?/) by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3519 on 2015-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a test_ros package in ros_comm from the Fuerte release. It contains only message and service definitions.
http://rosindex.github.io/p/test_ros/#fuerte-overview
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/fuerte-devel/test/test_ros

It looks like test_ros was renamed to test_rosmaster. test_rosmaster has all the same service and message definitions as the old test_ros package
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/indigo-devel/test/test_rosmaster

test_rosmaster is listed on the packages packages page in the wiki.
http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?distro=indigo&name=test_rosmaster

The wiki page says the website for test_rosmaster is just rosmaster
http://wiki.ros.org/rosmaster

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2015-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-11-11**:
The messages are duplicated at several positions. But the tests need a "test_ros" package:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/rosmsg/test/test_rosmsg_command_line.py

I just wanted to add test cases for a Pull Request, but that's quite hard if the test cases don;t run...